# Does RedShift support computed columns?

Tags: redshift, computed-column

In PostgreSQL I can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
   Effective_Date timestamp NULL,
   Max_Age_Date timestamp generated always as dateadd(month, 5, Effective_Date) stored
);
```

How do I create a computed / generated column in RedShift?

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532084/how-do-i-add-a-calculated-column-in-sql-workbench-j

But that is not a real computed column.

Comment: There is no mention of it at:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html